# Where to find Qt5 color schemes?

Tags: color, dark-theme, qt

A few months ago, I began to fall in love with dark themes & tried to apply them everywhere I could. I eventually ran into the need to theme Qt5 applications, since they don't follow native desktop themes (as far as I know).

When using the Qt5 configuration tool, I noticed that the appearance of Qt5 applications is the combination of a *style* and a *color scheme*, so what I really needed was not a "dark theme", but a dark color scheme. So, I went looking for places to download one, but I couldn't find any! The only fully-usable color schemes I was able to find were links to Google Drive conf files given by [a post on a obscure Linux tips blog](https://fixmynix.com/lxqt-dark-style/). Web searches didn't turn up anything more useful than that. Even opendesktop.org doesn't seem to host any Qt5 color schemes anywhere.

So my question is, where can one find pre-made Qt5 color schemes to download? Is Qt5 still too new for any online themeing resources to be available? Or are Qt5 color schemes something users are supposed to create themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are generally called QtCurve themes so you'll find them if you search for that.

https://store.kde.org/browse/cat/119/

Themes on this site will generally include colors. Here is a popular dark theme: https://store.kde.org/p/1005491/

While the color schemes and qtcurve will work on GNOME/GTK (with qtcurve installed) many of the themes on this website also include themes for example for Plasma which is KDE.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the Qt5 Configuration Tool

> qt5ct

You can very easily create and then edit your own color themes there with color selectors.

Comment: This is nice to know, but I was looking for a place to get pre-built themes instead of having to write my own. Thanks though!